# Why does my DropDownList always return back to the 0 value?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-select

I have a website with a dropdown list and several lists. The intention is:
If you select a name in the dropdown list, the lists should be populated with data relevant to the selected name.

If you select another name in the dropdown list the name related to the 0 index always returns.

**What do I have to change in my source, so that the name I've selected is shown?**

**And how can I give ViewBag.ID_Artiest the "key"-value of the selected name?**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <label for="ArtiestenLijst">Selecteer artiest:</label>

    <% using (Html.BeginForm("OnChange", "HitdossierController", FormMethod.Post, new { ID_Artiest = "DoChange" })) %>
    <% { %>
        <%= Html.LabelFor(x => x.ID_Artiest)%>
        <%= Html.DropDownListFor(
                x => x.ID_Artiest,
                new SelectList(ViewBag.ArtiestenLijst, "Value", "Text"),
                "-- Selecteer artiest --",
                new
                {
                    @onchange = @"this.form.submit();"
                })%>
    <%} %> <br />
    <br />
    <div id="divPartialView">
        <%= Html.Action("Detail_Hitdossier", new { AID_Artiest = ViewBag.ID_Artiest })%> <br />
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your quick answer.

I've found the solution by using the **FormCollection**. After selecting, I call the action Index again but overloaded as a HttpPost.

In the Index.aspx you find this code:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Hitdossier", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmArtiest" })) %>
<% { %>
    <label for="ArtiestenLijst">Selecteer artiest:</label>
    <%= Html.DropDownList("ID_Artiest",
            new SelectList(ViewBag.ArtiestenLijst, "Value", "Text"),
            "-- Selecteer artiest --",
            new
            {
                @onchange = "document.getElementById('frmArtiest').submit();"
            })%>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div id="divPartialView">
        <%= Html.Action("Detail_Hitdossier", new { AID_Artiest = ViewBag.ID_Artiest })%> <br />
    </div>
<%} %>
```

... and in the Controller you've the following **ActionResult** 's:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? AID_Artiest=810000)
{
    ReadSelectie(AID_Artiest.Value);

    ViewBag.ID_Artiest = _ArtiestInfoModel.ID_Artiest;
    ViewBag.ArtiestenLijst = _ArtiestInfoModel.ArtiestenLijst;

    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection ACollection)
{
    int iID_Artiest;
    int.TryParse(ACollection["ID_Artiest"], out iID_Artiest);
    return Index(iID_Artiest);
}

public ActionResult Detail_Hitdossier(int? AID_Artiest)
{
    int iID_Artiest = AID_Artiest ?? 810000;

    return View(GetArtiestData(iID_Artiest));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely that when you're posting back to the controller, you're not repopulating the "ViewBag.ArtiestenLijst" with your drop down list. I would use a Model to store your values and not use the ViewBag. That way, when you return the view back from your post, it will still contain your list of items.